# Pass Context or make use of view.getContext(). Does it really matter?

Tags: java, android, android-context

So, I have two options to get the `context`.  See the following two methods (cleaned up for clarity) from a Utility Class.

```java
public static void onCopyClicked(Context context, ImageView copy){
    copy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public static void onCopyClicked(ImageView copy){
    Context context = copy.getContext();
    copy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

I can pass the context or simply get it from the view.  I guess I prefer the second one since it is one less parameter to pass, but I wonder if the `getContext()` call is costly.  I'm not trying to micromanage my code, but rather just trying to follow best practices (if one exists for this case).

Comment: As long as `copy` is not null and laid out, the second one will work

Comment: I've wondered about this for years with my game, which averages several references back to the main activity context every tic. It works either way, but I too typically went with the second option as it just seemed a bit cleaner, as long as getContext() didn't take much time (((Activity) getContext()) in my case). I'm surprised this question only has 51 views, nice example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second option.

Calling `getContext()` on a `View` is not costly. The `context` reference is saved when a `View` is created and the `getContext()` method just returns it.

Check the [constructor source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/View.java#2709) and the [`getContext()` method](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/view/View.java#6045) of a `View`.